# Rails dynamic routes flattened

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have something like this:

```
get '/received/:resouce' => 'received#index'
get '/received/:resouce/:resouce_id' => 'received#show'
post '/received/:resouce' => 'received#create'
put '/received/:resouce' => 'received#update'
delete '/received/:resouce' => 'received#delete'

get '/sent/:resouce' => 'sent#index'
get '/sent/:resouce/:resouce_id' => 'sent#show'
post '/sent/:resouce' => 'sent#create'
put '/sent/:resouce' => 'sent#update'
delete '/sent/:resouce' => 'sent#delete'
```

But this is very verbose. I want to use the `scope` and `resources` methods of routes for rails.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
scope '/sent/:resource' do
  resources :sent, param: :resource_id, path: '/'
end
scope '/received/:resource' do
  resources :received, param: :resource_id, path: '/'
end
```

Comment: I tried for some time buy couldn't come up with a better solution

Comment: Thanks for trying @RichPeck. I found this to be the best solution